# regex_replace doesn't replace the hyphen/dash

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm using regex_replace in postgreSQL and trying to strip out any character in a string that is not a letter or number. However, using this regex:

```
select * from regexp_replace('blink-182', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$', '')
```

returns 'blink-182'. The hyphen is not being removed and replaced with nothing ('') as I would expect.

How do I modify this regex to also replace the hypen - I've tested with many other characters (!,.#) and they are all replaced correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `select regexp_replace(...)` instead (the replace function in the from part does not really make sense)

Comment: Removing the `$` from the end picks up the `-`, however, I assume you need that. Might be better if you tell us what you need the regex to do in general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You currently replace a run of non-alphanumeric characters *at the end of the string only*. I guess your tests were mainly strings of the form `foobar!#` which worked because the characters to remove were at the end of the string.

To replace every occurrence of such a character in the string remove the `$` from the regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

(also I changed the `*` into a `+` to prevent zero-length replaces between every character.

If you want to retain whitespace as well you need to add it to the character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
```

or possibly

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+
```

If the regex in the beginning was in fact correct in that you only want to remove non-alphanumeric characters from the end of the string but you *also* want to remove hyphen-minus in the middle of a string (while retaining other non-alphanumeric characters in the middle of the string), then the following should work:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$|-
```

[maniek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192512/maniek) points out that you need to add an argument to `regexp_replace` so it will replace more than once match:

```
regexp_replace('blink-182', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$|-', '', 'g')
```

Comment: This seems to also remove any whitespace though. Is there a way to allow whitespace?

Comment: Sure, just add whitespace in the character class.

Comment: You need `regexp_replace('blink-182', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', 'g')` , otherwise only one replacement will be made.